# ActiveMQ JDBC Master/slave journaling

Tags: activemq-classic

The documentation says "JDBC Master Slave cannot use the high performance journal".
If the reason for this is slave is not aware of journal and if Master goes down the messages are lost
 ... in that case how does it work in Shared file system scenario?

Answer (score 1):

- JDBC Master Slave cannot use the high performance journal since the journal is based on the local filesystem and not shared with the slave.
- So if you need performance and master slave, you should go for a shared filesystem instead. There are a number of options, but typically every larger IT organization has something preferred way to handle shared file systems, such as Windows shares, NFS or what not. Of course, you have a single point of failure in the filesystem so that might need to be fail over secured as well.
- The third way is the "shared nothing" approach, where the master broker replicate itself to all the slave brokers. If the master fails, a new master is elected among the remaning slaves, and the master starts to replicate it's state. This setup is using the LevelDB replication and Apache ZooKeeper for master election.

All these three HA strategies are documented well on this [page](http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html).